# How to skip Javascript output in Webpack 4?

Tags: css-loader, webpack-4, mini-css-extract-plugin

I use Webpack 4 in a project where I only need to compile and bundle styles so far. There's no Javascript.

Here's the config I have:

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'css/bundle': path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/scss/index.scss'),
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'static'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/scss'),
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
  ],
};
```

The problem is that it outputs two files: bundle.css and bundle.js. Is there a way to configure Webpack so that it doesn't output the Javascript bundle? I tried to navigate the docs, tried a dozen different things, but it didn't really work.

One important note here is that if I remove the css-loader, bundling fails. So while css-loader is most likely responsible for outputting the bundle.js file, I'm not entirely sure how to avoid using it.

Comment: I guess this is not possible, because wp is in the first place a JavaScript bundler. I would use a plugin which cleans up the dist folder after emit..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**March 2021:**

In Webpack 5, [`on-build-webpack` plugin](https://github.com/kossnocorp/on-build-webpack) did not work for me.

I found this:

[Webpack Shell Plugin Next](https://github.com/s00d/webpack-shell-plugin-next)

The project I’m working on we’re using Webpack 5 as a build tool for a CSS pattern library. Therefore, we didn’t need the `main.js` in our `dist`.

Run `npm i -D webpack-shell-plugin-next`

Then in `webpack.config.ts` (just showing the pertinent parts):

```
import WebpackShellPluginNext from "webpack-shell-plugin-next";

module.exports = {
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "static/dist")
    },
    plugins: [
        // Run commands before or after webpack 5 builds:
        new WebpackShellPluginNext({
            onBuildEnd: {
                scripts: [
                    () => {
                        fs.unlinkSync(path.join(config.output.path, "main.js"));
                    }
                ]
            }
        })
    ]
};

export default config;
```

Answer (score 5):

**webpack-extraneous-file-cleanup-plugin** has no effect with webpack 4.12.0.

I can suggest to remove *bundle.js* manually with **on-build-webpack plugin**:

```
var WebpackOnBuildPlugin = require('on-build-webpack');

// ...

plugins: [
    // ...

    new WebpackOnBuildPlugin(function () {
        fs.unlinkSync(path.join('path/to/build', 'bundle.js'));
    }),
],
```

Comment: I ran the cleanup task on npm level, but this solution looks sharp, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is just the way that webpack currently works.  However, we are not alone in this problem!  There's [a plugin](https://github.com/AnujRNair/webpack-extraneous-file-cleanup-plugin) to cleanup any unwanted files:

install the plugin:

```
yarn add webpack-extraneous-file-cleanup-plugin -D
```

and then in your config:

```
const ExtraneousFileCleanupPlugin = require('webpack-extraneous-file-cleanup-plugin');

plugins: [
  new ExtraneousFileCleanupPlugin({
    extensions: ['.js'],
    minBytes: 1024,
    paths: ['./static']
  }),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The [webpack-remove-empty-scripts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-remove-empty-scripts) plugin, compatible with webpack 5, cover the current issue. It remove unexpected empty js file.

Answer (score 0):

I simply delete the unneeded output with rm in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "npm run clean && webpack -p && rm ./dist/unneeded.js"
 },
```

Comment: That’s the problem: it’s okay to run consecutive commands once, but it won’t work the same way in watch mode. I could use [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) and run a clean task, but it feels unnatural, as if I’d be using two wrong tools instead of the right one.